# my android emulator is not working on vs code

Tags: android, flutter

Hey thanks for taking the time to read the question..
I cant connect my android emulator to my vs code for some reason, it says there's an error
so when I open a new terminal on my visual studio code and type flutter run there's always an error. it says that Google pixel API 30 is connected but then I get some error regarding the emulator and I just cant use the emulator. if someone can help me out with this it would really help me a lot..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please give us more details to understand issue

Comment: You need to post the error logs.